# Fragment move from one Fragment to another by sliding as well as button click

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I have a view that consist of three buttons, a fragment and a ViewPager. If you press button1 then fragment one should be shown. If you press button two then fragment two is shown. If you press button three then fragment Three is shown. As well as sliding should happen from from fragment one to fragment tow and fragment two to fragment three. The problem is that If I execute separate fragment and ViewPager it runs. But I want both in single layout. Error show in this line : fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fr); and error is :The method replace(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, Fragment);
so please anybody tell me how to fix this problem. I used both fragment as well as ViewPager. Can I use both in single layout.

How can I solve this problem so both will happen like sliding as well as fragment move by button click?
MainActivity.java class

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {    

    private PageAdapter mPageAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewpages_layout);        
        initialingpaging();
    }

    private void initialingpaging() {

        List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment1.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment2.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment3.class.getName()));
        mPageAdapter = new PageAdapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);        
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        pager.setAdapter(mPageAdapter);
    }

    public void selectFrag(View view) {

        Fragment fr;            
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            fr = new Fragment1();               
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            fr = new Fragment2();
            break;
        case R.id.button3:
            fr = new Fragment3();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fr);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

// PageAdapter.java class

```
public final class PageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> fragments;
    public PageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {

        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {     

        return this.fragments.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {     

        return this.fragments.size();
    }
}
```

//Fragment1.java, Fragment2.java and Fragment3.java class are like below code:

```
public class Fragment3 extends Fragment {   

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {     

        if(container == null) {

            return null;
        }
        return (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment3_layout,container,false);
    }
}
```

//fragment1_layout.xml, fragment2_layout.xml and fragment3_layout.xml are like similar code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

//viewpages_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >    

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="selectFrag"
        android:text="Fragment 1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:onClick="selectFrag"
        android:text="Fragment 3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="selectFrag"
        android:text="Fragment 2" />    

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+android:id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"/>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_place"
        android:name="com.example.viewpageexample1.Fragment1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp" />    

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Did you get this fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have imported the right Fragment class.

There is Fragment class in **android.app** and in **android.support.v4.app**.

I think you are using **android.support.v4.app.Fragment** and `fragmentTransaction.replace(int, Fragment)` method uses **android.app.Fragment**.

So to make it work, change `getFragmentManager()` to `getSupportFragmentManager()` and fix imports to use classes from **android.support.v4.app**.

Answer (score -1):

I think instead of 3 buttons, you should try action bar tabs..here is the code for the same.

1. add implements clause to your class definition.

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener{
   ```
2. Initialize the following inside your class
       ActionBar bar;
       ViewPager viewpager;
       PageAdapter ft;
3. In onCreate, replace your code with this.

   ```
   viewpager = new ViewPager(this);
   viewpager.setId(R.id.pager);
   setContentView(viewpager); 
   ft = new FragmentPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
   viewpager.setAdapter(ft);

   final ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
   bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
   bar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);

   bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Fragment1").setTabListener(this));
   bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Fragment2").setTabListener(this));
   bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Fragment3").setTabListener(this));

   viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

       @Override
       public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           bar.setSelectedNavigationItem(arg0);
       }

       @Override
       public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       }

       @Override
       public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       }
   });


   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.start_screen, menu);
       return true;
   }


   @Override
   public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }

   @Override
   public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    viewpager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
   }

   @Override
   public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }
   ```
4. In viewpager_layout, only have this. Remove everything else.

   ```
   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
       android:id="@+android:id/viewpager"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:layout_marginTop="100dp"/>;
   ```
5. PageAdapter code should be like this.

   ```
   public class PageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

   public PageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
       super(fm);

   }

   @Override
   public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {

       switch (arg0)
       {
       case 0:
           return new Fragment1();
       case 1: 
           return new Fragment2();
       case 2:
           return new Fragment3();
       default:
           break;
       }
       return null;
   }

   @Override
   public int getCount() {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       return 3;
      }
   }
   ```
6. Your Fragment xml / change background color between 3 xmls to see results.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:id="@+id/fragment1"
       android:orientation="vertical" 
       android:background="#00FF33">
   </LinearLayout>
   ```
7. Your Fragment1/2/3 code

   ```
   public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

   View myFragmentView;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   }

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
   Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);

     return myFragmentView;
   }
   }
   ```

checkout http://semycolon.blogspot.in/2014/11/first-android-app-step-5-homescreen.html. It has a complete explanation with source code.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: As suggested, I have put the code here with explanation. Hope this is ok now